# WebService SPC Brasil: O sistemas não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado - SOAPAction:""

Tags: delphi

Estou consumindo o WebService do SPC Brasil e importei o WSDL do seguinte endereço:
https://treina.spc.org.br/spc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService?wsdl

Após importar o WSDL e implementar a consulta ocorre o seguinte erro:

O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. - URL:https://treina.spc.org.br:443/spc/remoting/ws/consulta/consultaWebService - SOAPAction:""

No WSDL a propriedade SOAPAction está vazia mesmo.

Se alguém souber o que pode estar acontecendo, fico grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, que neste caso era só configuração do windows.
Abri o Internet Explorer, em configurações >> Opções de Internet >> Avançadas e mudei/marquei as opções "Usa SSL" e "USA TLS".

Após isso, o serviço passou a funcionar e pude concluir o trabalho.